# Python import class from local folder

Tags: python, pydev

I have 2 classes. The first is named test and goes as following:

```
import textbox
class test:

    a=textbox("test")
    a.run()
```

---

the second class is textbox and goes as following:

```
class textbox():
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string=string
    def run(self):
        print string
```

i get this error

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\edoras\gui\test.py", line 4, in test
    a=textbox("test")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I use the pydev eclipse plugin

Comment: Can we assume (as @silvado does in his question) that `textbox` class is declared inside `textbox` module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
a = textbox.textbox("test")
```

or alternatively use

```
from textbox import textbox
```

Comment: This is only true if this assumption that the class `textbox` is located in the file `textbox.py` is true.

Comment: Yes, I was guessing so from the `import` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the error you mention, but your print statement in text box.run is wrong:

```
print self.string
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling directly the module textbox, which is not allowed.

Maybe it contains an omonymous function? In that case you should call

textbox.textbox('test')

(the first textbox would be the module name, and the second a function inside it)